# EditText "ime" option is not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

Iam newbie to android. I started working with EditText. I had tried Imeoption(imeoption ="actionsend") for the editText but cant find any button showing send. I had even given "singleline=true"  but no use. can anybody tel me the solution?

here is code

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/search" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/postal_address" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:ems="10" 
android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
android:imeOptions="actionSend" 
android:inputType="text" 
android:singleLine="true" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: share you edittext code here

Comment: <EditText
     android:id="@+id/search"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/postal_address"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:ems="10"
     android:hint="@string/search_hint"
     android:imeOptions="actionSend"
     android:inputType="text" android:singleLine="true" />

Comment: what device are you using? imeOptions do not work on all devices - particularly some older ones...

Comment: @WinPhone7User It won't show `send` as button name, but return button will act like Send Button.

Answer (score 0):

check this code , its working for me

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lineView"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Comment: still its not working for me..Is there any version dependency

Answer (score 0):

Fallow my steps. it is working from me.

Change the EditText in xml file like this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineView"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Next In Activity(.java) file

```
EditText passWord=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
passWord.setImeOptions(6);// 6 for actionSend; 4 for actionDone;
```

Done.